# Making the Lightning Inspector work on a Lightning Component presented in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en) Chrome extension installed and this works when Lightning Experience is turned on.

But when testing in Salesforce Classic where a Lightning Component is added to a Visualforce page via `$Lightning.use`, it generates this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: global.$A.getContext is not a function

with a link to this fragment of code:

```
// Since we were injected, Aura could already be available. If so, let the devtools know.
if(!global.$A || !global.$A.getContext()) {
    var _Aura;
    ...
```

Is there a way to make the Lightning Inspector work for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4 Apr 2017 it is now working. May be something I've changed in my code or something changed in the platform.